# How to implement claims based authentication in a java app?

Tags: java, wif, claims-based-identity

I'm currently working on a project where I'd like to use Claims based authentication (Using windows identity foundation) in one of my applications.

The only snatch is.. the solution I develop also has to enable claims based access to a java based application. And since I'm a .net developer, i have no idea what technologies are available to implement such a thing in java.

So the question is: Does java have libraries for building a claims enabled application?

Something like windows identity foundation or ADFS 2.0 in .net?

With kind regards,
Erwin

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?  I need to get a claims based app in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Good article here: [Identity Federation Interoperability – WIF + ADFS + Sun’s OpenSSO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2010/06/30/identity-federation-interoperability-wif-adfs-sun-s-opensso.aspx).

Note that this is not "standard" OpenSSO - it requires [Federation](https://opensso.dev.java.net/public/use/docs/opensso/pdf/WSFedHowTo.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a java developer either, but I've seen people use this: https://opensso.dev.java.net/

But I haven't used it myself.